# Rails with Devise: current_user.id == params[:id], returning false, should be true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails app using Devise. I'm trying to have an If statement on my view page, but for some reason I am not getting a return of true. See below...

View Page

`<%= current_user.id %>`
`<%= params[:id] %>`
`<%= current_user.id == params[:id] %>`

This returns

1 1 false

Am I missing something? 1 and 1 are equal so why is this not returning true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
current_user.id.to_s == params[:id].to_s
```

Comment: params[:id] comes back as a string and current_user.id comes back as a fixnum. I knew it had to be something obvious.

Comment: no problem, dont forget to thumb ups the answer and mark it as solved ! cheers !